# why can't I package this maven project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jenkins

when I open the maven project in eclipse it compiles fine but when I do "mvn package" it fails.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by doing "update maven project" from within eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

AnnotationProcessorFactory (APT) is a standard tool and supplied as part of the JDK. You are missing tools.jar into your classpath. Check your Java installation.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are running Maven from a JDK. 
Also, for Java 7, try to force a Dependency to **tools.jar**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
   <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
   <version>${java.version}</version>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```